# Uploading file to rails 4 DB with a rake task, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rake-task

```
    namespace :import do
           desc "imports data from a csv file"
            task :data => :environment do
            require 'csv'
            CSV.foreach('lib/tasks/file.csv') do |row|
                first = row[0]
                last = row[1]
                city = row[2]
                state = row[3]
                zipcode = row[4].to_i
                email = row[5]
                File.create(first: first, last: last, city: city, state: state, zipcode: zipcode, email: email)
            end
        end
    end
```

When I type in rake import:data the error I end up with is

```
    rake aborted!
    NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for File:Class
    lib/tasks/import.rake:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /lib/tasks/import.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The name of the model you're importing to is  called `File`?

Comment: You're calling `create` on `File`.  `File` is a defined class in Ruby, and you probably don't want to use that name for a model in your application.  You could namespace it, or just come up w/a better name.